# Can't connect to google cloud engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Yesterday I connected to my instance successfully but now cloud says following:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

In `ssh.cloud.google.com` there is infinite waiting

Comment: You can get more details with flag: --verbosity=debug with [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh). In addition, verify the serial port (console) logs (Click on the instance>under Logs > click Serial port 1 (console). You can also [login directly to the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) to verify the instance logs. There are several possible causes for eg: disk space full etc. Also, add more details to the question along with the log information or any other relevant.